# how i can render a json for an list of ActiveRecord in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

for example, 
i got a list of Target in my controller

```
@targets = @user.targets.all
```

then i want to render @targets as json result for client ajax call.
in Target class define, i have some column i don't want to render.
i know when render single @target, we can use

```
:only
```

or

```
:except
```

but, how to deal with the list?

i tried

> @targets.each do |target|    xxxx end

to merge the json result, failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override [`as_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/as_json) in your `Target` class and specify which columns you don't want to be rendered.

More details [here](http://jonathanjulian.com/2010/04/rails-to_json-or-as_json/).